# Redirect when forward slash is at end of URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is located in the root HTML directory and is shown below.

I also have test.php and manual.png also located in the root HTML directory, and test.php is just the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src="manual.png"></body></html>
```

When I put http://www.myDomain.com/testit in the browser, the page is rendered and manual.png is displayed.

When I put http://www.myDomain.com/testit/ in the browser (not the trailing forward slash), the page is still rendered, but the manual.png is a broken link.

What do I need to change to allow the image to be displayed when including the trailing slash (other than making all my links in my HTML absolute)?  If not possible, how do I then prevent the HTML page from being rendered in the first place if it has the trailing slash?  Lastly, please provide an explanation of what is going on.

Thank you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory, file, or link, don't do anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# replace my-page with test.php?p=my-page
RewriteRule ^(testit)/?$ test.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]   #Replaces file if "." is not in the string (i.e. it will not replace file.html, but will replace file

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a browser visits a URL without a trailing slash, it looks at it as a file. This means the base directory will be the file's parent directory. If the URL *does* have a trailing slash, the browsers sees it as a directory and makes it the base directory.

To prevent this problem, Apache has a module which automatically adds a trailing slash to directory requests. But since you're using rewrites, Apache won't add anything.

You can solve this by enforcing either a trailing slash, or the lack of one.

```
# The following should remove the trailing slash.
# Add it before your my-page -> test.php?p=my-page rule
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1
```

BTW, you can use [this site](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to test rewrite rules

Comment: Thanks Koen,  Can you elaborate on how I would remove the slash?

Comment: Just added something that might work, I can put some more thought into it if it doesn't ;)

Comment: Thanks Koen.  I like your recommended test site!  Any reason you did not include `^` at the start of the rule?

Comment: No particular reason, it's just looks simpler this way. Adding it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Koen, actually tried it, and the image still shows a broken link.

Comment: Does the RewriteRule works as far as removing the trailing slash? If it doesn't, you can add the `[R=301,L]` parameters.

Comment: Yes, the rule works perfectly to remove the trailing slash.  Maybe just the URL put into the browser, and not the URL of the image included in the HTML?  Tried adding your recommended flags.  It put `http://www.myDomain.com/var/www/html/testit` in the browser.

Comment: If the rule works as far as removing the trailing slash goes, the problem has to lie somewhere else. I can't really help you with that. :\